# How do i make a JS code send an array to a JAVA code and make the JS receive data from that JAVA code

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

Ok, so I've been trying to pass longitude and latitude to JS code and then I want the JS code to send an array of location (pairs of longitude and latitude) back to the JAVA code. I've managed to follow this guide [Reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) but I can't find its opposing pair of code that will help me send the and receive data from the JS to JAVA. The code so far is below:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    /* This one is responsible of sending any data that will be sent to the javascript code*/
    URL javascript;
    public URLReader() throws MalformedURLException{
        javascript = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    }
    public void send(String longitude, String latitude) throws Exception{
        String lon = URLEncoder.encode(longitude, "UTF-8");
        String lat= URLEncoder.encode(latitude, "UTF-8");
        URLConnection connection = javascript.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write("longitude =" + lon);
        out.write("latitude =" + lat);
        out.close();

    }
    /* This one is responsible of recieving any data that will be recieved from the javascript code*/
   public String[] recieve() throws Exception{
       String myArray[] = {};
       URLConnection yc = javascript.openConnection();
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
       String inputLine;
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
           System.out.println(inputLine);
       in.close();
       return myArray;
   }
}
```

The variable Latlng is the variable I want to send to my Android Studio code

```
latlng = {lat: parseFloat(position.coords.latitude), lng: parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)};
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make an AJAX request?

Comment: @ADyson I'm not sure what I need to make this work that's the issue. basically what I'm asking for is advice as to how to proceed from this point forward. right now, what I want is a way for my JS code to receive data from the JAVA code assuming that ill is using the above code. And a way to send data from the JS code to the JAVA code that can also be READ by the above code.

Comment: Are you talking about JS running in a web page, in a browser, or server-side NodeJS? Either way, you can easily Google how to make a HTTP request from either of those environments (AJAX is the way you make a HTTP request from browser based JavaScript).

Comment: P.s. are you actually running this Java code on a HTTP server? It's unclear.

Comment: @ADyson this JS code runs on the browser yes. and regarding the HTTP request part can you please provide any guide that I can follow to implement that part in my JS code. and can the HTTP request be read by the code ive provided above?

Comment: For making the request, just Google "Ajax request tutorial"...you'll find hundreds of examples. Try to find a modern one using the Fetch API if you can. As for the Java part, I'm not a Java expert sorry, but I know there are various frameworks for hosting Java based web apps e.g. JSP,  and others. I don't know how you're currently hosting or executing this code. But again I imagine you can find tutorials/documentation online. Or perhaps a Java programmer will see this post and have some more insight